# microbatch lookup in external database from spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a requirement where I need to process log lines using Spark. One of the steps in processing is to lookup certain value in external DB.

**For ex:** 
my log line contains multiple key-value pair. One of the key that is present in log is "key1". This key needs to be used for lookup call.
I dont want to make multiple lookup call sequentially in external DB for each value of "key1" in RDD .Rather I want to create a list of all values of "key1" present in RDD and then make a single lookup call in external DB.

My code to extract key from each log line would look as follows:

```
lines.foreachRDD{rdd => rdd.map(line => extractKey(line))
// next step is lookup
// then further processing
```

The .map function would be called for each log line, so I am not sure , how can I create a list of Keys which can be used for external lookup.

Thanks

Comment: you can use `collect` or `collectAsList` method after map, it will return as Array[Key] or List[Key].

Answer (score 2):

Use `collect`.

```
lines.foreachRDD{rdd => 
    val keys = rdd.map(line => extractKey(line)).collect()
    // here you can use keys List
```

Probably you'll have to use mapPartitions also:

```
lines.foreachRDD{rdd => 
    rdd.foreachPartition(iter => {
        val keys = iter.map(line => extractKey(line)).toArray
        // here you can use keys Array

    }
}
```

There will be 1 call per 1 partition, this method avoids serialization problems

Comment: Thanks.. Is there way , i can make 1 call per rdd instead of 1 per partition?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want this:

```
lines.groupByKey().filter()
```

Could you provide more info?

Comment: The "key1" i am going to use is just one of the column in log line. That is a key only for lookup . For example , i got 2 log line with key "key1" , i will lookup database for a certain value with this key. The result i get i will append to the log line and proceed further for processing. 

So basically, i am trying to accumulate list of keys on executors rather than on driver.